# Removing per-item permissions by powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint-list. In this list each item has its own user-permissions. Because of a design change I want to remove the item-permissions and get back to standard inherited permissions from the list.

Because there are hundreds of items in that list: Can this be done by a powershell-script? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem at technet:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-to-Reset-Unique-d885a93f

```
###############################################################################  
##  ADD IN SHAREPOINT SNAP IN IF NOT ALREADY LOADED ##  
###############################################################################  


if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {  
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"  
} 


###############################################################################  
##  SET VARIABLES FROM ARGUMENTS ##  
###############################################################################  

$webUrl = $args[0] 
$listName = $args[1] 
$listInherits = $args[2] 

# Varibale to hold document count 
$count = 0 

###############################################################################  
##  OPEN OBJECTS & RESTORE INHERITANCE ##  
############################################################################### 

try { 
    # Open the web and list objects 
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl 
    $list = $web.Lists[$listName] 

    # If the list should inherit, reset the role inheritance 
    if ($listInherits -eq $true) { 
        $list.ResetRoleInheritance() 
        Write-Host "Updated permissions on list." -foregroundcolor Green 
    } 

    # Get all items with unique permissions 
    $itemsWithUniquePermissions = $list.GetItemsWithUniquePermissions() 
    Write-Host $itemsWithUniquePermissions.Count "number of items with unique permissions found." 

    # Only update items if some exist 
    if ($itemsWithUniquePermissions.Count -gt 0) { 
        foreach ($itemInfo in $itemsWithUniquePermissions) { 
            $item = $list.GetItemById($itemInfo.Id) 
                $item.ResetRoleInheritance() 
            $count++ 
        } 

        # Display number of items updated 
        Write-Host "Updated permissions on $count items." -foregroundcolor Green 
    } 
    else { 
        Write-Host "No items with unique permissions exist, nothing to update." 
    } 

    # Dispose of web object 
    $web.Dispose() 
} 
catch [Exception] { 
    Write-Host "Exception encountered.  Please ensure all arguments are valid." -foregroundcolor Red 
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -foregroundcolor Red 
}
```